# fopen permission denied

Tags: php, lamp, fopen, ubuntu-10.04

I am getting the following error when I try loading one of my php pages:

> [Fri Apr 08 22:59:50 2011] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  fopen(tracking_id.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/basic.php on line 61

Line 61 is the second line from the script below:

```
$ourFileName = "tracking_id.txt";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($ourFileHandle, $trackingId);
fclose($ourFileHandle);
```

Anyone know how this can be resolved?

I am using Ubuntu as the OS, and apache as the webserver.

I used tasksel to install LAMP-server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a file called tracking_id.txt and execute the following command on it:

```
chmod a+w tracking_id.txt
```

Comment: Why is it that this is not a problem on my live server, but it is a problem on my development machine?

Comment: The folder in which the file exists on your development machine has different permissions than on your live server. It's possible that the owner of the folder is the web server user in one case, but a different user in the other, and hence PHP is unable to create new files.

Comment: I am also having same type of problem, but like the OP of the question i do not know what file is being built, the name is generated through script and a new file has to be kept under that name within a folder with a read & write permissions to owner, groups and others..... Can you help me out?